# Where do I get "Mercury" by MWR InfoSecurity?

Tags: penetration-test, android

Mercury is a really great tool for android pen-testing as well as android forensics. However, they stopped its development and now I get redirected to some product called drozer. Does anyone know where can I find mercury? I *have* googled for it but I didn't get any good results. I need to install Androguard, as Mercury is one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MWR InfoSecurity:

> Drozer **(formerly Mercury)** is an open source software, maintained by
>   MWR InfoSecurity

Also if you take a closer look at their logs, Drozer is what they were always headed for and Mercury was just a pre-name for (maybe) the incomplete version of what they intended to release. I don't know if you are specifically looking for an older release of Drozer (which is Mercury v2.2.1) or not but when you say:

> now I get redirected to some product called drozer.

It seems like you are unaware of the facts I mentioned above.
Hope this helps :-)